# Show camera preview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to have a preview of the camera in 2 views so I made a class `CameraSingleton`:
CameraSingleton.h:

```
@property (retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
@property (retain) AVCaptureSession *session;

- (void)addVideoPreviewLayer;
- (void)addVideoInput;
```

CameraSingleton.m:

```
@implementation CameraSingleton
@synthesize session;
@synthesize previewLayer;

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self setSession:[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addVideoPreviewLayer {
    [self setPreviewLayer:[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session]];
    [[self previewLayer] setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

}

- (void)addVideoInput {
    AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (videoDevice) {
        NSError *error;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoIn = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
        if (!error) {
            if ([[self session] canAddInput:videoIn])
                [[self session] addInput:videoIn];
            else
                NSLog(@"Couldn't add video input");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Couldn't create video input");
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create video capture device");
}
```

In both ViewControllers is this method implemented:

```
- (void)showPreview {
[cameraSingleton addVideoInput];
    [cameraSingleton addVideoPreviewLayer];

    CGRect layerRect = [[self.mainView layer] bounds];
    [cameraSingleton.previewLayer setBounds:layerRect];
    [cameraSingleton.previewLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect),
                                          CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];

    [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:cameraSingleton.previewLayer];
}
```

but I don't see the preview. I checked the IBOutlet for mainView and read Apple's documentation but I can't figure out the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you called [session start] ?

Comment: Isn't `[session startRunning]` only for starting to capture a video? I just want to have a preview without saving anything.

Comment: You are passing session to preview layer, you have to start session to get it work. It wont save anything if you wont set up any output.

Comment: I added this line to `showPreview`: `[cameraSingleton.session startRunning];` but it still shows nothing.

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong then, but you can try also adding [[[self view] layer] setNeedsDisplay]; after adding sublayer.

Comment: The view is still only white.